# XML to Json Mapping -Data weave script filtration on indexing

Tags: json, xml, indexing, mule, dataweave

I have to implement small logic in my code - here I am getting an XML  request and it has to be converted into JSON. Before converting I have to implement small logic and my input XML is :

```
<details>
  <mydetail>
    <Firstdate>2017</Firstdate>
    <futuredate>1</futuredate>
  </mydetail>
  <mydetail>
    <Firstdate>2017</Firstdate>
    <futuredate>2</futuredate>
  </mydetail>
  <mydetail>
    <Firstdate>2017</Firstdate>
    <futuredate>3</futuredate>
  </mydetail>
</details>
```

and my expected JSON is:

```
[
  {
    "Currentdate": "2017",
    "Nextdate: null

  },
  {
   "Currentdate": "2017",
    "Nextdate "1"
  },
 {
    "Currentdate": "2017",
    "Nextdate "2"
  }
]
```

**Logic Is**:
In response, if it is the first `Nextdate` in JSON then it will always be `null` else `Nextdate` will map to the previous value of `futuredate`.

I have written below data weave script, but it is not working.

```
payload.details.*mydetail map {
    Currentdate: $.Firstdate,
    Nextdate: null when $$==0 otherwise $.Seconddate [$$-1]  ,
}
```

But this script is not working and I'm not getting the expected result.
What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following script to get desired output

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload.details.*mydetail map  {
    Currentdate: $.Firstdate,
    Nextdate: null when $$ == 0 otherwise payload.details.*mydetail.futuredate[$$ - 1]  
}
```

Your script is having extra `,` while mapping `Nextdate` which caused error.

Comment: thanks Its working but can you help me to me explain "payload.details.*mydetail.futuredate[$$ - 1]" this syntax , how it works..

Comment: As you required the futuredate from previous object, `payload.details.*mydetail.futuredate` this returns array of futuredate like `[1,2,3]` and then next part is array index selector `[$$-1]` which returns futuredate value of previous object.